# What happens when we put AND-LISTS to background?

Tags: shell, job-control

I am trying to understand how shell manages process groups of members of AND-LISTS.

For example, Bash (and also dash) implements the following behavior:

1. `p1 && p2` - processes p1 and p2 have different groups.
2. `p1 && p2 &` - processes p1 and p2 have same group. p1 finishes with zero exit code and p2 is  executed.
3. `p1 && p2` - Then press Ctrl+z and run command `fg`. After that p1 finishes with zero exit code but p2 is not executed.

Why is case 2 different from case 1?
Why is case 3 different from case 2?
Is that POSIX-compatible?

Comment: Are you assuming `p1` and `p2` are simple (not compound) commands?

Comment: @Kusalananda, for simplicity, this assumption can be taken.

Comment: This is a highly complex problem. There is a related bug report in the POSIX bug tracking system and we did delay the discussion because we could not yet find a solution. The general problem with POSIX and the shell is that job control is highly underspecified.